# Hide 'Save' button on asset form

Tags: servicenow

[image]

[image]

In OOB asset form save button is not there, but it is present in my instance.I want to hide this save button.As you can  see there are many UI actions, how I can determine which one works an asset table?(all ui actions are on global table)
Please help me out....

Comment: Do you want to prevent access to save, or just to hide the button?

Comment: @Kirk I just want to hide it

Answer (score 1):

As you have correctly pointed out, there are 4 global UI Actions with the name "Save".  They all have different combinations of the true/false fields: "Form Button", "Form Context Menu", and "Show Insert".

You want to de-activate the one that has "**Form Button**" value of "True" and "**Show Insert**" value "true".

The only reason it is being displayed is because of the condition isAdvancedUI() is returning as true. This is because the system property 'glide.ui.advanced' has been set to true. By setting this to true, a number of useful options in the context menus, become visible as form buttons (Save, Insert, Insert and Stay). Unfortunately one of the save buttons that appears, is not very desirable, because there is already a "submit" for inserting new records.

This is why it is perfectly OK to disable this button globally.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a *Client Script*. Keep in mind that hiding the button is obfuscating the Save button rather than restricting the access.

I tested this on a personal instance and it worked.

- **Name**: Hide save button
- **Table**: Asset [alm_asset]
- **UI Type**: Both
- **Type**: onLoad
- **Active**: Checked
- **Inherited**: Checked
- **Global**: Checked

**Script**

```
function onLoad() {
    var items = $$('BUTTON').each(function(item){
        if(item.innerHTML.indexOf('Save') > -1){
            item.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

This will load when any form view loads that extends the **Asset [alm_asset]** table because the **Inherited** box is checked. This is important because you can have hardware assets, license assets, and so on.

When this runs, it will search each button for *Save* and then hide it if matched.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer here (https://community.servicenow.com/thread/261454) is exactly what you're looking for. Identify and override the save buttons (ones with "form button" checked) and you'll be good to go.

Side note: Generally it's a good idea to avoid changing the out-of-box UI actions, especially for something simple like hiding the button. Using a method like adding a condition can result in you 'owning' the button and make upgrades more time consuming. That said, there is a mechanism called 'UI Action Visiblity' that can control visibility for views without modifying (and owning) the UI Action itself. I've used this in the past and it works well. 
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-servicenow-platform/page/administer/list-administration/concept/c_ControllingVisibilityWithRoles.html